# CONSERVAR EL IDENTITY EN MI BASE DE DATOS

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, javafx, transacciones

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de gestión de una juguetería y he tenido problemas al momento de implementar las transacciones y es que cuando hago una mala inserción de un procedimiento almacenado (a propósito) mi transacción no despliega nada...
Por lo que pensé en utilizar TRY - CATCH y **cuando ejecuto las líneas y pruebo mi procedimiento almacenado en SQL-SERVER el identity no se altera y todo funciona sin problemas**... Pero al consumir mi procedimiento almacenado de manera externa (Java FX) es cuando no inserta, pero si altera el identity de mi tabla...

A continuación les muestro mi procedimiento almacenado en SQL-SERVER

```
USE [Jugueteria]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_insertarMarca]
    @Nombre varchar(50),
    @IdMarcaGenerado int out
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Marca (Nombre) VALUES (@Nombre)
    SET  @IdMarcaGenerado = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

   --@IdActual guarda el valor previo a una mala insercion--
    DECLARE @IdActual INT = @IdMarcaGenerado-1;
   --Restaura el valor anterior en caso de una mala insercion--
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (Marca, RESEED, @IdActual);
   --Muestra mensaje de error y Numero de error--
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS Numero_Error,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS Mensaje;
    END CATCH
   --Finalmente se muestra el identity actual (despues del try-catch)--
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (Marca)
END
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a mejorar el procedimiento almacenado... Puesto que lo que quiero es no perder el identity en mis tablas...

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Por qué te es tan importante no perder valores del identity? El propósito principal de una columna identity es garantizar de que los valores generados sean únicos, no necesariamente en secuencia. Perder algunos valores cuando las transacciones hacen rollback es 100% normal.

Comment: @sstan, suponía que al estar esto desalineado podría afectar directamente a la lógica de mi sistema. Pero si esto no afecta en nada pues no le veo ningún inconveniente. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta